# Injecting custom repository implementation in a service layer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am written a custom JPA implementation using the [Spring JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) as reference, and I wish to inject aforementioned implementation in a service layer, but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. I have also gone through the [following documentation as well](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations). My application is a Spring boot application.

The documentation does not say how to initialise my custom repository implementation. I have tried to follow the [following instructions](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-method-in-all-repositories).

My Service layer.

```
@Service
public class ProfileService implements IProfileService {

  @Autowired
  private IQuizRepository quizRepository;

  . . . . Some methods defined here. . . . 
}
```

My JPA interface

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IQuizRepository extends JpaRepository<Quiz, Long> {

  Quiz registerQuiz();

}
```

Concrete class

```
public class QuizRepository extends SimpleJpaRepository<Quiz, Long> implements IQuizRepository {

 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager em;

 public QuizRepository(Class<Quiz> clazz, EntityManager em) {
   super(clazz, em);
 }

  /**
   * Initialises and returns a quiz attempt.
   */
  @Override     
  public Quiz registerQuiz() {
    String uniqueKey = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
    Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
    quiz.setQuizId(uniqueKey);
    Score score = new Score();
    quiz.setScore(score);
    score.setQuiz(quiz);
    this.save(quiz);
    return quiz;
  }

}
```

When I don't annotate `QuizRepository` concrete class with `Repository`, then I get the following error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field quizRepository in com.myproject.service.ProfileService required a bean of type 'com.myproject.repository.IQuizRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.myproject.repository.IQuizRepository' in your configuration.
```

But when I annotate `QuizRepository` with `@Repository`, then I get the following error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.myproject.repository.QuizRepository required a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' in your configuration.
```

My project has a combination of JPA interfaces inheriting from JPA repository, and concrete implementations.

Comment: what's the error log, please paste it

Comment: there is no error log. I don't know how to set the dependency.

Comment: spring boot will auto inject the entity manager with this constructor, so you should run your application first to see the result

Comment: But I am writing a custom concrete implementation.

Comment: no matter what the jpa custom implementation is, you should write the spring boot application that have **main(String[] args)** method to run it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your constructor needs to have these exact two parameters:

```
public QuizRepository(JpaEntityInformation<Quiz, Long> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

instead of `public QuizRepository(Class<Quiz> clazz, EntityManager entityManager)`

Comment: But the concrete implementation is parameterisied. I can't define generic types.